# Which port can i use for my socket?

Tags: c#, sockets

Hello I am a beginner and i want to know how I can decide which port I can use for my socket?

Thanks.

Comment: @user729975 - Please make some effort to title your questions meaningfully, rather than just typing 3 terms related to the subject matter. That's what tags are for.

Answer (score 4):

You can use any port that is not already used by any application.
I suggest to stay away from 1-1024 ports.These ports are used by common applications.
Here is a list of app's and what ports they are using : [List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)

Answer (score 3):

**For best practice you should your ports in the range of 49152-65534**

**Port numbers 0-1023 – Well known ports.**

These are allocated to server services by the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA). e.g Web servers normally use port 80 and SMTP servers use port 25.

**Ports 1024-49151- Registered Port**

These can be registered for services with the IANA and should be treated as semi-reserved. User-written programs should not use these ports.

**Ports 49152-65535-Free to use these in client programs**

These are used by client programs and you are free to use these in client programs. When a Web browser connects to a web server the browser will allocate itself a port in this range. Also known as ephemeral ports.

Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ports less than 1024 are usually reserved for system operations, after that you just need to avoid anything that you know will be in use on the machine(s) your program may run on.  If you don't know that, then make the port a configurable setting.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use any port you like but suggest using one that is
1) not currently being used by another application (run resmon.exe on windows7 to see what ports are in use)
2) not a well known port of another service (eg 443, HTTPS)
3) not an OS 'reserved' port; that is a port less than 1024.

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) list for more