# Socket exception in tcp listener

Tags: c#, sockets, exception, tcp

I trying to run this code:

```
listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any,port: 80);
            listener.Start();
            socket = listener.AcceptSocket();
```

but it throws the following exception:
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

What may be the reason?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which port can i use for my socket?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882247/which-port-can-i-use-for-my-socket)

Answer (score 1):

It might be forbidden to use a port below 1024 if you are not Administrator. Try a port like 8080 instead. see also [Which port can i use for my socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882247/which-port-can-i-use-for-my-socket)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Well, I think I included the essential parts: Ports below 1024 might lead to problems, and suggested one which is generally not too bad, especially since he tried to use port 80, which is standard HTTP.