# SocketException thrown when invoking TcpListener.Start()

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I am aware that there is already a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593077/socket-exception-in-tcp-listener). However, the only answer there does not solve my problem.

Here is my code:

```
TcpListener TcpListener = new TcpListener(localaddr: IPAddress.Any, port: 8080);
TcpListener.Start();
```

Executing `TcpListener.Start();` gave me this error:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'An attempt was made to access a
>   socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions'

I have already defined an inbound security rule inside my firewall to make Port 8080 publicly accessible (I am aware that this is generally not recommended, but I am temporarily doing this for testing purposes):

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I run `netstat -o`, I am able to verify that Port 8080 does **not** already have an established connection.

For what it is worth, I am starting a TcpListener on an Azure virtual machine.

Any suggestions on how I can fix the `SocketException`?

**UPDATE:**

When I run `netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0.0.0:8080`, I see the following result:

> TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING      4

Could the SocketException have been thrown because there already is a `TcpListener` listening on Port 8080?

I tried terminating the existing `TcpListener` by running `taskkill/pid 4 /F` (in order to see whether `SocketException` will still be thrown after terminating it), but didn't succeed:

> ERROR: The process with PID 4 could not be terminated. Reason: Access
>   is denied.

Comment: Found [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46588590/3559686) which fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did the PID of 4 really not set alarm bells ringing before you tried taskkill? It's *unusually low*. In most windows systems I've worked on, it's been the system "process" that *is* the OS.

It's probable that something has registered to use that port as part of a [URL reserved via HTTP.SYS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/http/namespace-reservations-registrations-and-routing).

If you have IIS running look for sites that are running on that port.

Comment: Found [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46588590/3559686) which fixed my problem.